# My datasource isn't updating when changing the binding list using a task

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, data-binding

I want to bind my combobox's data source using a binding list. The binding list contains a collection of *Client* instances. I managed this and it works well, but because reading from the database takes long I decided to use a task. And now once the binding list is updated via the task the combobox still has no values.

I wanted to use a normal thread at first, but struggled so switched to using a task(pretty much the same thing I guess thing I guess). So a solution using threads would be just as useful.

```
    public partial class frmJobCreation : Form
    {
        public frmJobCreation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        BindingList<Client> clients = new BindingList<Client>();

        private void frmJobCreation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbxRtojClient.DataSource = clients;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                clients = new BindingList<Client>(Client.GetClients());
            });
        }
    }
```

Where `Client.GetClients()` is a static method that returns `List<Client>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form load event you have `cbxRtojClient.DataSource = clients;` and then you are updating the `clients` object in the Task. But this is never going to update the ComboBox.

A Task in C# (wrt winforms) should ideally perform a task and return its results so that it can be updated in the UI. The UI update should ideally be done in a `ContinueWith` continuation task which is run in the UI context. We should always update any control in the context of the UI thread. [Check this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=1).

```
Task.Run<BindingList<Client>>(() =>
{
    // return all the clients to 'ContinueWith' task
    return new BindingList<Client>(Client.GetClients());
})
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // Result is a dynamic property and holds the output of its previous Task. BindingList<Client> in this case.
    clients = t.Result;

    // Update UI
    cbxRtojClient.DataSource = clients; 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // ensures calling the ContinueWith task to be run in the UI thread.
```

To know more about Task Parallel Library (TPL) [follow this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-of-n).

Comment: Thank you, this worked and the link you added helped me understand why. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, the combobox datasource count didn´t match with items.count , this workaround works for my problem.